# $state.go within a .config Angular

Tags: angularjs

Using the following to catch 401's in my app

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(rejection){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            if(rejection.status == 401){
                  $state.go('login', {}, {reload: true, inherit: false});
            }
            defer.reject(rejection);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
});
}]);
```

I know the `$state.go` won't work as it can't be injected. How do I pull up my login page in this state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Martin wrote, you can inject $state as you inject $q, but as you noted you've got a circular dependency because $state is dependent on $http (to get the views), but now $http configuration is dependent on $state as well.

To break the circle, you can use the $injector service, and manually inject $state after all dependency checks are done:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector) { // inject $injector service
    return {
        'responseError': function(rejection){

            var $state = $injector.get('$state'); // manually inject $state service using $injector

            var defer = $q.defer();
            if(rejection.status == 401){
                  $state.go('login', {}, {reload: true, inherit: false});
            }
            defer.reject(rejection);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
});
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing about interceptors and decorators is that they are configured during the config phase, but they execute in the run phase. So you can use $state in the intercepter, you just need to inject it the same way you are injecting $q.

Comment: This causes a circular reference. Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $state <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state

Answer (score 0):

It is easier by far to not have to inject $state.

Just use $scope.$emit:

```
$scope.$emit("go", { page: "home" });
```

And in the base controller:

```
$scope.$on("go", function(status, whereTo) {
    $state.go(whereTo.page);
});
```

Currently I'm not using anything other than page, but this can be easily extended to handle parameters as well.

Comment: My answer seems to be appropriate, because you will be able to have logic in one place to handle any stuff that may need to be done to handle the action. For example, you may want to save the current scope somewhere on the server before they move on.